# SmtpJS not working with Elastic Email: "Failure sending mail. The server must be configured corectly."

Tags: javascript, smtpjs

After pressing send I get an error message saying:

> Failure sending mail. The server must be configured correctly.

```
function sendEmail() {
    Email.send({
        Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com 2525",
        Username : "myemail@gmail.com",
        Password : "PASTED ELASTIC SERVER PASWWORD",
        To : "randemail@gmail.com",
        From : document.getElementById("email").value,
        Subject : "New site email ",
        Body : "And this is the body"
    }).then(message => alert(message));
}
```

I thought something wrong with the way I wrote the port, but wasn't able to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<main>
        <div class="container my-5">
            <form>
                <label for="name">Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" required />
                <label for="email">Email:</label><input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" required />
                <label for="subject">Subject:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="subject" required />
                <label for="message">Message:</label><textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" onclick="sendEmail(event)">
                    submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <!-- place footer here -->
    </footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <script>
        function sendEmail(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
            var messages = document.getElementById("message").value;
            var body =
                "Name: " + name + "<br>Email: " + email + "<br>Message:" + messages;
            console.log("hello");
            Email.send({
                SecureToken: "7c90d80b-5966-4447-be77-c0121d3bdaf9",
                To: "reciever@gmail.com",
                From: "youremail@gmail.com",
                Subject: "sample na this",
                Body: body,
            }).then((message) => alert(message));
        }
    </script>
```

try my code you should put a preventDefault so it will not render